# Android Studio changing Relative layout to ScrollView

Tags: android

I am a beginner in Android studio programming and I am making a small app for my arduino. 
The screen size is too small for a Relative layout, so now I am trying to change it to a ScrollView and I don't know how to. So can anyone help me? 
Thank you!

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/testView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtString"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtString"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/testView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Shrani nastavitve"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonOn"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Beri nastavitve" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sensorView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Kot zamika = "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sensorView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Min obrati  = "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sensorView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Trenutni obrati :  "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/testView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/testView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sensorView0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Čas zamika = "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:max="100"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonOff"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:max="180"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekBar4"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/seekBar4" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar3"
    android:max="5000"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/seekBar2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sensorView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Čas mirovanja = "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar4"
    android:max="3000"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonOff"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonOff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sensorView0"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sensorView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sensorView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sensorView4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put above `RelativeLayout` inside the `SrollView` as below:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">


       <!-- Your whole code goes here -->

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried it you way... there are no errors but the rendering is fishi :) the app works but it does not scroll

Comment: Do you have more elements below screen now?
Any textview is hidden?

Comment: elements are pushed one on another. My Xperia Z5 died and now im testing on an old Xcover. Mybe its something with the Android on the phone. I tested on my girlfirends Lenovo ( has a bigger screen) and everything fits perfectly. I don't have a 3.65" svreen preview. There is one but everything is different.

Comment: It works! I didn't see it because my seekbars are extended from left to right. If i touch the right side of the screen:) Tank you so much! I will be able to work the rest out by myself!!! +1

Comment: welcome buddy...

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the GUI editor to help you. Under container, choose ScollView and drag it to your screen. Then add your elements. It will work.

As an alternative, you can surround your current code by

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
```

and

```
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Make sure to remove the line

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

from your existing layout, that line needs to be on the highest parent.

What this does is making a layout with only the scrollview in it. Then it places all components in the view, so you will have a scrollable view with everything inside it.

Comment: Why another RelativeLayout? ScrollView should be the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace   `<RelativeLayout` to 
`<ScrollView        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">`
      but your component cannot be loaded because ScrollView only have one direct child

Below Lines can be put into relative layout which will be on child to scroll view..

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/someComponent"
```

and some similiar positioning codes

*addition you should use scale pixel (sp) instead density pixel(dp) in a TextView.textSize